# Why do I keep getting curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none?

Tags: curl, certificate, ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric

I'm on ubuntu 16.04. I'm running git version 2.26.2 and curl version 7.47.0. I keep getting the error the the cert file is gone, but I go to that directory and the file is there. Also I've tried updating my certificates, but it won't download anything new.

I'm trying to pull the latest hyperledger Fabric code using the command:

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question and does not belong on stackoverflow.com - it belongs on https://askubuntu.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: that said, my best guess is that you're getting the error on another account than you're checking the file's existance on, and that there's a permission issue there. for example, are you getting the curl error on the `www-data` account? then run ```sudo su www-data /bin/sh -c 'namei -l /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'``` , what do you get?

Comment: I discovered the issue was my vpn. Once I turned off my vpn and set my network settings to "bridged" it worked. Thanks for letting me know where I should put my question. That is very helpful.